# MongoDB get last updated set of documents of each category

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have this document structure:

```
{
 ...,
insertionDate: 'someDate',
product: 'cool jacket',
color: 'red',
store: 'north store',
}
```

The thing is this collection stores every change a product has ever had.
At this moment I have the following code to retrieve all the products in one store with one color of a set previously defined.

```
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange'];    
collection.find({$and: [{store: store)}, {color: {$in: colors}}]});
```

The problem is that I get all the historical data, for example I can get 'cool jacket' in each color 4 times, because it appears multiple times in the database with different insertionDate.

How do I get the last insertionDate of each product?

Comment: Wast that answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collection.find({$and: [{store: store)}, {color: {$in: colors}}]}).sort(insertionDate: -1)` will sort them according to the last inserted date.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using aggregate query with three pipelines.

1. `$match` to match the desired store and colors.
2. Use `$sort` to sort by `insertionDate` desc order.
3. `$group` to group by product Name or product Id. While grouping `$first` accumulator will help to get the recent inserted product.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tested code:

```
await Collection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        color: { $in: colors }
      }
    },
    { $sort: { insersionDate: -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: '$product', doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } }
  ]);
```